# Java complains about invalid method declaration, return type required

Tags: java, return

it's for a `JOptionPane` `YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION` I did the following method:

```
public NewCard()
    {
        int ans = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you wish another card?", "7 in 1", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION );
        if (ans == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {
            ans = 1;
        }

        if (ans == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
        {
            ans = 2;
        }

        if (resp == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
        {
            ans = 3;
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

I want to read this answer from the main but a grammatical error appears. It says:
`Invalid method declaration; return type required` but I tried to write a return in all `if` statements and got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You must have the return *type* in the function declaration.

Your function returns an `int`, so:

```
public int NewCard() {
```

See the `int` there.

If you don't want to return anything, use `void`.

Comment: ohh i forgot that... thanks a lot. (I've to wait 9 minutes to acept your answer)

Comment: @user3763656: also, methods in Java conventionally start with a lowercase letter. It should be spelled `newCard()`. And why do you return 1, 2, 3 iinstead of returning `ans` directly and let the caller compare the answer to the JOptionPane constants? Or return a boolean indicating if the user chose to accept another card or not?

Answer (score 0):

This really should be a comment, but I needed the formatting.

You need to be careful when you reuse a variable like ans.

The values of the following constants are:

```
JOptionPane.YES_OPTION = 0;
JOptionPane.NO_OPTION = 1;
JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION = 2;
```

You could have just as easily added 1 to ans as coded the 3 if statements.

The way you wrote your code:

```
    if (ans == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {
        ans = 1;
    }

    if (ans == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
    {
        ans = 2;
    }

    if (resp == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
    {
        ans = 3;
    }
```

If ans = 0 (the YES option), you set it to 1 in the first if.

Then ans (your ans, not the original ans) = 1 (the NO option).

The same thing happens in the 3rd if.

So, if your user clicks on the YES button, you return a 3.  If your user clicks on the NO button, you return a 3.  Same for the CANCEL button.  You return a 3.

Either use two different variables, change your second and third if to an else if, or just add 1 to ans.